# How to Replace Nan and Inf with a specific Value (IFERROR Function in Excel) using Pipe function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I am creating a columns using math formulae's in R, and I am coming across cases which has `NaN` and `Inf` after the calculation. All these columns are done using pipe function (%>%). But unfortunately I am running into issue with replacing the `Nan` with `Inf`.

Can someone suggest a way to do an do this using Pipe Function. Is this possible to be done in Pipe Function.
The code I was writing is given below. And I got stuck here.

```
X <- X %>% 
  mutate(X1_Value = (X1*Y)) %>% 
  mutate(X2_Value = (X2*Y)) %>% 
  mutate(Check1 = ((X1_Value -X2_Value)/X1_Value )) %>% 
  mutate(Check2 = abs((X1_Value -X2_Value)/X1_Value ))
```

I have selected a few columns which include the data. Using this code:

```
X1 <- X %>% 
select(Key,Check3)
```

I have selected a small reproduceable data from my main data set. This is the dput:

```
structure(list(Key = c("XYZ-1", "XYZ-2", "XYZ-3", "XYZ-4", "XYZ-5"), Check3 = c(NaN, NaN, Inf, 2.5, -1.7)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Can someone try this excel iferror function on that Check3 column in the above data set so that I can replace the Nan and Inf to 0 or 1. Based on situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use this as solution.

```
X1 <- X1 %>%
  mutate(Check4 = ifelse(Check3 == "NaN" ,1,Check3)) %>%
  mutate(Check4 = ifelse(Check4 == "Inf",1,Check3)
```

I believe this should do it. This covers the idea which you are looking for.

Do have a look and let me know if you got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
X1 <- X1 %>% 
  mutate(Check3 = ifelse(is.na(Check3)==T|
                           Check3==Inf,0,Check3)
         
  )

library(tidyverse)
X <- X %>% 
  mutate(X1_Value = (X1*Y),
         X2_Value = (X2*Y)) %>% 
  mutate(Check1 = ifelse(is.na((X1_Value -X2_Value)/X1_Value )==T,Inf,
                         (X1_Value -X2_Value)/X1_Value ),
         Check2 = ifelse(is.na(abs((X1_Value -X2_Value)/X1_Value ))==T,
                         Inf,abs((X1_Value -X2_Value)/X1_Value ))
         )
```

Comment: I am talking about the X1 Dataset not in the previous one which is X.

Comment: Try the first code. In your query you mentioned you had difficulty in replacing the Nan with Inf. Therefore the below code replaces the Nan values with Inf. You can change the condition according to your need

Comment: Hi Chris thank you for the effort, Saw the first part but I wanted to do this in a pipe function